# Django values function rename key of dict

Tags: python, django

In my databases design

```
id | key | value
 1 | ABC | 123
```

and what i trying to do

```
data.objects.filter(id__in=list).values('key', 'value')
```

and it return

```
[{'key': 'ABC', 'value': '123'}, ... ]
```

but instead of that, i want to do

```
[{'ABC': '123', ... ]
```

Noted: The result list will be 800k rows, because of the performance issues, i try to avoid using loop and want to use django feature to make it like this.

I will make sure the value from 'key' is unique.

Comment: What's the purpose of this massive values QuerySet? If it's 800k rows you will probably always run into performance issues whatever you do

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(data.objects.filter(id__in=list).values_list('key', 'value'))
```

Note, if you have duplicate values for `key` then you will only get the last value for that key

Comment: Thanks for remind and thanks a lot, you're save my time !